# vim powerline doesnt shows fonts in gVim

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

I installed powerline and downloded all the fonts. Configured _vimrc to the font FiraMono and it worked but I can't change the font into nothing else
I installed RobotoMono in my windows But I cant set my gVim into RobotoMono font.

When I edit _vimrc into RobotoMono then airline status bar goes weird and font become Fixedsys [My _vimrc screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNc9n.jpg)
I am using gVim on windows  searched for solution but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried vi.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: yeah I got several links when I googled.
But nothing worked.Should I post issue there ?

Comment: Yes, that is a dedicated stackechange for just this type of occasion.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thank you for your response

Comment: if the question/problem is about a particular plugin/script, best way to go is using the issue tracker of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When GUI font becomes *fixedsys* on gvim, it means gvim cant find the font you specified (in this case, RobotoMono); so it fallbacks to its default font thats *fixedsys* and of course unpatched *fixedsys* is not contain fancy powerline symbols and as the result, airline statusbar becomes weird.

As you noted your patched FiraMono font works, the problem seems to be with font name that you are entered in your `vimrc` so first from gvim menu go to: `Edit > Font > show more fonts` and from there select the RobotoMono font that you Installed, after selecting that font a name will appear underneath dropdown list; thats the right name you should enter in your `vimrc` file. By the way i have got these patched fonts installed and the names are:

`Roboto Mono for Powerline
Roboto Mono Light for Powerline
Roboto Mono Medium for Powerline
Roboto Mono Thin for Powerline`

AND do not forget to scape spaces in them with `\`

P.S. You dont need `let g:Powerline_symbols="fancy"` in your vimrc.

Comment: When I go to _Edit > Font_ there is no Roboto font in that list. I found it in _"show more fonts"_ link in the bottom.Can you tell me the code to be add into my _vimrc.If I want to set the following font.
**Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline**
It is Directly copied from that font select window in gVim.

Comment: ok, thats there, just found the name and set it in your vimrc. `set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ derivative\ Powerline:h14`

Comment: Now gVim is not opening.
I copied your exact code in to my _vimrc.

Comment: try this: `set guifont=Ubuntu_Mono_derivative_Powerline:h14`

Comment: I changed font into
_set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ powerline_
It worked.Still don't know the issue with Roboto

Comment: Thanks for your response. Atleast I changed my font.

Comment: By the way if you can change the font to Roboto or Ubunto Mono from `Edit > Font > show more fonts` , here is a link that teaches you how to find and set it in your vimrc to make it default: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font